# how can we scp a zip file to another server and unzip it on the target server

Tags: linux, scp, zip

I need to scp a .zip file to another server and then unzip it on the target server. How can I do that in linux

Comment: Issue the commands is how to do it. Not seeing a problem here - or do you not know the commands? Not sure if this is a real question in its current form.

Comment: The zip file is huge and there is very little space on the source server so I want to unzip it on the target server only

Comment: So... I'm still not seeing an issue. After the file is on the target machine, login on the target machine - over `ssh` if you do not have physical access - and run  `unzip filename.zip`.

Comment: I do that using ssh servername unzip path/to/file.zip and it even shows me a message saying it has unzipped but when I go to the target location it is still zipped. So I'm not sure where the problem is. If I do a ls -ltr instead of zip it shows me that same file but it is not unzipping it

Comment: Unzip doesn't remove the .zip file. You can remove it with `rm` once you're finished with it.

Comment: Please write all the commands you have issued in to the question, not as a comment. Please include any error messages or test you ran to check as well.

Answer (score 7):

First copy your file to the server, and then `unzip` it.

```
scp <file name> user@host:/path/to/destination ; ssh user@host 'unzip /path/to/file on server'
```

Comment: Using compression (`-C`) when transferring a compressed file is a bit overkill.

Comment: @Kusalananda, True, edited.

Comment: I was really hoping there was a single command that would stream the zip command output to the server, and the server save it to a zip file.